# How can one get the ID of a jpg saved in res/drawable-hdpi folder?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have a jpeg. I dragged it into an auto-generated folder called drawable-hdpi under the res folder.
All the tutorials just use "R.drawable.myimage" but I get an error "cannot be resolved to a variable"
Below is my code:

```
import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;

public class MyCanvas extends View{

    Bitmap bmp;

    public MyCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.85849);   
    }

}
```

Note that the name of my jpg file is 85849

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you need to use the correct `R`. Get rid of the line

```
import android.R;
```

or else qualify the `R` in your `decodeResource` call with your app's package name (or import the correct `R`).

Second, your resource file names cannot start with a number. They have to be legal Java identifiers.

Comment: @323go - It was never incorrect as far as what information it had; just incomplete. :)

Comment: EDIT: It worked! Thanks a ton. Before you go, what is "R" and what does it do? Why did deleting that statement work? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Sorry for double commenting. I experimented a little and found that which ever pre-made drawable folder I place my image in (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc) I can reference it from all of them. Additionally, there is a folder called ic_launcher in each drawable folder. So the question becomes, if I wrote R.drawable.ic_launcher, which image gets referenced? I really really appreciate it. Just two questions. I don't mean to make this into a discussion. You answered my question already and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2316667 - The Android build tools automatically generate an `R.java` file from your resource files and add it to your project's package (as declared in the manifest). The image that gets referenced by `R.drawable.ic_launcher` depends on the particular device configuration in effect when the code is executed. (All copies of `ic_launcher.jpg` are included in the .apk file.) For more info, see the guide topic [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).